# Is it faster to just unlink a file or check if it exists first?

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to optimize my web application and I don't know where to get good information about the speed differences between using an unlink command or a file_exists command. See here:

```
@unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".jpg");
@unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".png");
@unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".gif");
```

Versus

```
if (file_exists(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".jpg"))
    @unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".jpg");
if (file_exists(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".png"))
    @unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".png");
if (file_exists(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".gif"))
    @unlink(graphics_url_root."/items/entry_img_".$_SESSION['userID'].".gif");
```

Comment: You know, you could also write a function. Would look less messy :). Btw, I don't really think this is what slows down your system. You should find the bottleneck first, and optimize accordingly.

Comment: checking if file exists before unlinking the file is the proper way to code... with that you dont have to supress warnings as well

Comment: Sudhir, there seems to be some disagreement. Barmar below suggests that a file exists check is built into unlink and says it's faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's faster to just unlink. It's one system call instead of two. And the code in the kernel that implements unlink has to first test whether the file exists, so you're just duplicating that code.

The problem with using `@unlink()` is that you won't get notified of other types of errors, such as permissions problems. So if you use the `file_exists()` check, you shouldn't suppress errors.